# What is the significance or importance of console.log([]+0);

Tags: javascript, console.log

I was asked this question in a interview, I did not know what is the importance of this or why is it used.
I did not receive the answer to this puzzling question. 
Please tell me why is this important.

Comment: answering that demonstrates that you understand javascript dynamic type system

Comment: do you know what the output is (without running it)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't understand the question. The significance of it is that you can do `+` on pretty much anything and it gives you garbage most of the time.

Comment: @ggorlen - is `0` garbage?

Comment: You don't get `0`, you get `"0"`. Why should concatenating an empty array and a digit stringify the digit? That's the most unexpected behavior I could think of and I don't see any practical value for it. What's happening is the array is stringified but since it's empty, it looks like `""` and then you have `"" + 0`.

Comment: The `console.log` calls `toString()` on the array and the `0` int in order to log it, and so the result is `"0"`. If you were to do `console.log([1,2]+0)` you'd get `"1,20"`, since the `[1,2].toString()` is `"1,2"` and `0.toString()` is `0`

Comment: This has neither any _"significance"_ nor _"importance"_. The question (if the title is the actual question) is just useless... Yes, JavaScript has some strange rules when working with different types. But there's a spec where you can look it up if you really need it. If you concatenate an array with a number you have other problems in your code.

Comment: @holtc _"The console.log calls toString() on the array and the 0 int in order to log it"_ - It's not `console.log()` that defines the output of the operation. It's the overloaded `+` operator that does.

Comment: @holtc ... `typeof ([]+0)` is `string`, so the console.log does not effect the type of result

Comment: The proper interview answer is "if that's the code you write here and rely on, I think I'll look elsewhere, but thank you for your time."

Comment: @IngoBürk thank you so much, it was a job interview where I have to work as a React Native developer. I have self-taught myself MEAN & MERN stack and I have a good practical experience in web development. And this the questions I receive from job interviews when instead they should be looking at the stuff I learnt! 
If you would like to see the stuff I learnt I will be happy to send it to you privately.

Comment: @holtc I have not typed type of, the literal question is what is the importance of console.log([]+0);

Comment: @Andreas I am giving you the word verbatim question that was thrown at me by an interviewer. This is exactly what they asked me.